# Cursor jumps into textarea when auto-height is added

Tags: javascript

I add an automatic height to textarea, enter a lot of text and there is a problem with the cursor.
Cursor jumps up and down when you press any key inside the text added to textarea.

How to ensure that when pressed any keys on keyboard  the cursor not not jump but remains in the same place

```
set autoheight(value) {
    this.#autoheight = Boolean(value);

    if (!this.#textarea.isConnected) return;

    if (this.#autoheight) {
      this.#textarea.style['overflow-y'] = 'hidden';
      this.#textarea.style.height = this.#minHeightTA > this.#textarea.scrollHeight
                                  ? this.#minHeightTA + 'px'
                                  : this.#textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
      this.#textarea.addEventListener('input', this.#handleTextareaInput);
    } else {
      this.#textarea.style['overflow-y'] = '';
      this.#textarea.style.height = '';
      this.#textarea.removeEventListener('input', this.#handleTextareaInput);
    }
  }
```

```
 #handleTextareaInput = () => {
  this.#textarea.style.height = 0;
  this.#textarea.style.height = this.#minHeightTA > 
  this.#textarea.scrollHeight
                            ? this.#minHeightTA + 'px'
                            : this.#textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of `#handleTextareaInput`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
#handleTextareaInput = () => {
  // Store the current cursor position
  const startPos = this.#textarea.selectionStart;
  const endPos = this.#textarea.selectionEnd;

  // Update the textarea's height
  this.#textarea.style.height = 0;
  this.#textarea.style.height = this.#minHeightTA > this.#textarea.scrollHeight
                                ? this.#minHeightTA + 'px'
                                : this.#textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';

  // Restore the cursor position
  this.#textarea.setSelectionRange(startPos, endPos);
}
```

In this implementation, the #handleTextareaInput function stores the current cursor position using the selectionStart and selectionEnd properties of the textarea before updating the textarea's height. After the height has been updated, the function restores the cursor position using the setSelectionRange() method of the textarea.

With this implementation, the cursor should stay in the same position when typing in the textarea, even as its height changes dynamically.

Comment: the cursor also jumps, but now always down the screen